# What exactly `systemctl --user enable SERVICE` means?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I expected `systemctl --user enable SERVICE` to start the service on login, which is not happening. Then what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Is your user session using systemd?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can I check this in any way? I'm running `arch linux`. And `systemd` is [the default](https://www.archlinux.org/news/systemd-is-now-the-default-on-new-installations/) since `2012-10-13`. I installed my OS this summer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Have you followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User ?

Comment: Apparently, yes. But I missed the fact that when it starts, it brings up the target `default.target`. I just copied [the file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.3.29/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.service.in) as is and failed to realize that I've got yet to change the target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It makes the unit start on first login of a user, but for that corresponding unit file should have `WantedBy = default.target` or something along the lines. Because [when user instance of `systemd` starts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#How_it_works), it brings up the `default.target` target.

Comment: My `chrome-remote-desktop.service` has `[Install] / Alias=chromoting.service / WantedBy=default.target`, but I still have to start it manually on first login, any idea?

Comment: @tokland Have you enabled the service? `systemctl is-enabled chrome-remote-desktop`

Comment: `$ systemctl --user is-enabled chrome-remote-desktop` -> `enabled`

Comment: @tokland `systemd --user` instance is not launched on login? Maybe [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#How_it_works) will provide some clues.

Answer (score 3):

`systemctl --user enable SERVICE` will do nothing unless the related unit file has an `[Install]` section. the `[Install]` section lets `systemd` know which symlinks to set up with `enable` is used. From [the docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BInstall%5D%20Section%20Options):

> Unit files may include an "[Install]" section, which carries
>   installation information for the unit. This section is not interpreted
>   by systemd(1) during runtime; it is used by the **enable** and **disable**
>   commands of the systemctl(1) tool during installation of a unit.

Answer (score 0):

> systemd --user runs as a separate process from the systemd --system process. User units can not reference or depend on system units or units of other users.

Cannot have

```
After=network.target network-online.target
```

Comment: Is that first paragraph a quote?  If so, what is it from?  How does any of this answer the question? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416659)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).